# changing image tag attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, function, attributes

How do I complete the execute function, such that when the Next Image button is clicked, the next image in the images array is shown, and when I get to the end of the array, it should start from the beginning of the array.. so essentially, the Next Image button acts like a way to cycle through the images in the images array.
NB: the image at the first index of the array is already shown. So when I click the button, the image at the second index should be shown.. and so on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick='execute()'>Next Image</button>
    <div>
      <img src='https://bocageanimalhospital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F431-cat-face_4888130.png' />
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const images = [
  'https://bocageanimalhospital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F431-cat-face_4888130.png',
  'https://catdoctorofmonroe.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F408-cat-B_4888072.png',
  'https://aux.iconspalace.com/uploads/cat-clean-icon-256.png'
    ]

    function execute() {
  
    }

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a simple index tracker for the array while looping and reset if it reaches the end of the images array.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <button onclick='execute()'>Next Image</button>
  <div>
    <img id="image-holder" src='https://bocageanimalhospital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F431-cat-face_4888130.png' />
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  const images = [
    'https://bocageanimalhospital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F431-cat-face_4888130.png',
    'https://catdoctorofmonroe.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F408-cat-B_4888072.png',
    'https://aux.iconspalace.com/uploads/cat-clean-icon-256.png'
  ]
  var cIndex = 0

  function execute() {
    cIndex = cIndex + 1
    if (cIndex > images.length - 1) {
      cIndex = 0
    }
    document.getElementById("image-holder").src = images[cIndex]
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep an index variable outside of the `execute` function and increment it with every click of the `Next` button. If the index value exceeds the length of the `images` array then reset this by `0`.

```js
const images = [
  'https://bocageanimalhospital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F431-cat-face_4888130.png',
  'https://catdoctorofmonroe.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F408-cat-B_4888072.png',
  'https://aux.iconspalace.com/uploads/cat-clean-icon-256.png'
];

const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next-btn');
const image = document.getElementById('image');
let imageIndex = 0;
image.setAttribute('src', images[imageIndex]);

const execute = (event) => {
  imageIndex++;

  if (imageIndex >= images.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }

  image.setAttribute('src', images[imageIndex]);
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', execute);
```

```html
<img src="https://bocageanimalhospital.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/iconfinder_1F431-cat-face_4888130.png" id="image" />
<button id="next-btn">Next</button>
```